# Issue having swipe to dismiss list view appear

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement a swipe to dismiss list view as the child of a column so I can add a row of buttons below it but nothing is appearing on the screen when this renders and I am getting no errors.

```
final goals = List<String>.generate(20,(i) => 'item ${i+1}');

class AddButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context,int index){
              return new Dismissible(
                key: new Key(goals[1]),
                onDismissed: (direction){
                  goals.removeAt(index);
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: new Text("Item Removed")
                  ));
                },
                child: new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("${goals[index]}"),
                )
              );
            },
            itemCount: goals.length,
          )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Reference for what I'm trying to implement: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a variable to reference the current goal being built. Then, I've created a key from the item and inside the `onDismissed` function, I've added the required `setState` method. This example requires the use of a `StatefulWidget`, not a `StatelessWidget`.

**NOTE**: As of Dart 2.0, the `new` keyword is *optional*.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context,int index){
              var item = goals[index];
              return Dismissible(
                key: Key(item),
                onDismissed: (direction){
                  setState(() {
                    goals.removeAt(index);
                  });

                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: new Text("Item Removed")
                  ));
                },
                child: ListTile(title: Text("$item"))
              );
            },
            itemCount: goals.length,
          )],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you I was confused regarding the stateless widget part, I was following a tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzOONgeCVKg . Not sure why he used a stateless widget here

Comment: To be fair, you actually don't need a `StatefulWidget`, I think it was because in your code `Key(goals[1])` this part messed you up because you were setting the widgets to the same key. @Sachu

Comment: I see I'll be more aware of the keys they get a little tricky thanks again